# jquery validations on ajax callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm trying to get my form to validate before using an Ajax request to submit the form to my asp.net.I am new to Jquery Ajax.Please any body help me.Thanks in advance.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
             var data = {
                 details: {
                     GroupName: $("#txtGroupName").val(),
                     Description: $("#txtDescription").val(),



                 }
             };
             $('#form1').validate({

                 rules: {
                     "txtGroupName": {
                         required: true,
                         minlength: 5
                     },  
                     "txtDescription": {
                         required: true,
                         minlength: 5
                     }


                     },
                     messages: {
                         "txtGroupName": {
                             required: "You must enter your group name",
                             minlength: "group name must be at least 5 characters long"
                         },
                         "txtDescription": {
                             required: "You must enter your Description",
                             minlength: "Description must be at least 5 characters long"
                         }


                 },
                 submitHandler: function (form) {

                     $.ajax({
                         url: "AddGroup.aspx/SaveData",
                         data: JSON.stringify(data),
                         dataType: "json",
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                         success: function (result) {

                             alert(result.d);




                         },
                         error: function (xhr, ajaxxOptions, thrownError) {
                             alert(thrownError);
                         }




                     });
                     $("#txtGroupName").val("");
                     $("#txtDescription").val("");
                 }
             });

         });


     });
```

and my html page looks

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">


            <div>
                <input id="txtGroupName" type="text" runat="server" name="txtGroupName" placeholder="Group Name"/>
            </div>



            <div>

                <textarea id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription" runat="server"  placeholder="Description"></textarea>
            </div>   
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" /> 
            <input id="btnLoad" type="button" value="Load Data" />



    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  However, you would **NOT** put the `.validate()` method inside a `click` handler of any sort.  The `.validate()` method is ***only*** used for initializing the plugin and the `click` event is automatically captured by the plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

         $('#form1').validate({
             rules: {
                 "txtGroupName": {
                     required: true,
                     minlength: 5
                 },  
                 "txtDescription": {
                     required: true,
                     minlength: 5
                 }
             },
             messages: {
                 "txtGroupName": {
                     required: "You must enter your group name",
                     minlength: "group name must be at least 5 characters long"
                 },
                 "txtDescription": {
                     required: "You must enter your Description",
                     minlength: "Description must be at least 5 characters long"
                 }
             },
             submitHandler: function (form) {
                 var data = { ... };
                 $.ajax({
                     ....
                 });
                 $("#txtGroupName").val("");
                 $("#txtDescription").val("");
             }
         });

 });
```